# "Once you have finished" or "when you will have finished" are they synonymous?

Tags: grammar

And why do we use present perfect to describe future if the first expression is correct?
Please describe it to me in a plain way because unfortunately I cannot find any sufficient information on it on the Internet.

Comment: We don't say "when you will have finished" but "when you have finished".

Comment: or "when you finish"

Comment: or "when finished"

Comment: @WeatherVane, I`m sorry, but why? Future perfect is meant to describe a completed action in the future, isn`t it? Is this expression grammatically incorrect, or it  simply sounds unnatural?

Comment: If you type **present perfect future** into thee search box you'll find a number of previous questions on the topic.

Comment: '... when you will have finished' is used as a deleted form of the prepositional phrase 'by when you will have finished', in sentences like "You need at least four days to finish decorating these rooms. I'll come back to see you in about a week, [by] when you'll have finished."  It needs a reference time (or equivalent):  '[T], by which time you will have finished' (or should have). // '  ... once you have finished' is a temporal conditional marker. "Once you have finished, give me a ring." / "You can go and play with your friends once you have finished."

Comment: @Edwinashworth thank you